# Condition equivalent to Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

How to show this?

> Let $(X,\cal T)$ be a topological space. For $x\in X$, let $\cal U$ be the family of all open neighborhoods of $x$. Show that: if $\bigcap\limits_{U\in\cal U}\overline U=\{x\}$, for all $x\in X$, then $X$ is Hausdorff.

Here $\overline U$ is closure of $U$.

Comment: Hint: if $y \neq x$, find a $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $y \notin \overline{U}$.

Comment: I tried that if $x\ne y$ in $X$ but for every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects with some neighborhood of $y$. Then I somehow want to show that then $y\in \cap_{U\in\cal U}\overline U$.

Comment: FYI. Another condition, equivalent to Hausdorff, is that $\{(p,p):p\in X\}$ is closed in the product space $X\times X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\ne y .$ You are given that $y$ does not belong to the closure of any open $U$ with member $x .$ So there is such a $U$ with $x\in U$ and $y$ not in the closure of $U$. So $U$ and the complement of the closure of $U$ are disjoint open sets, one containing $x$ and the other containing $y .$ So the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: 32 answers = it's about time to learn how to type properly mathematics in this site, lest many people won't even read your posts. For example, you have to enclose your formulae between dollar signs to produce nice-looking ones, and \neq\ between dollar signs will render $\;\neq\;$

Comment: Go to the Help page, to the Help Center. Under "Our Model", go to "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"

Comment: Thanks , I am trying .How did you get the  belongs to symbol ,the stylized epsilon to came out in ,I can get x $\epsilon$ U

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\;x\neq y\implies \exists\,S\in\mathcal U\;$ s.t. $\;y\notin \overline {S_y}\;$ , otherwise $\;y\in\bigcap\limits_{U\in\mathcal U} \overline U=\{x\}\implies x=y\;$. But $\;S\subset \overline{S}\;$, so $\;y\notin S\;$ .

But $\;y\notin \overline {S}\;$ means that there exists an open neighborhood $\; V\;$ of $\;y\;$ s.t. $\;V\cap S=\emptyset\;$ ... complete the little stuff left to prove the claim.